# how debug a Firefox extension?

Tags: javascript, debugging, firefox-addon-webextensions

if we have a html and JavaScript code beside it and there is undefined variable in my JavaScript I can see error in Firefox development tool(F12).
now i developing an extension but i can't see error any where.

I read in [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Add-ons/Setting_up_extension_development_environment) about Setting up an extension development environment but that isn't help me.

i see similar questions in stackoverflow but they didn't help me.

```
<html>
<p id='p1' onclick='add()'>1</p>
<script>
function add(){
p1 = document.getElementById('p1')
p1.innerText++
}


observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations){
  console.log(mutations)
});
observer.observe(p1,{
  childList :true
});
</script>
</html>
```

in this case if i wrote p2 instead of p1 i see in DevTools Console something like : Uncaught RefrenceError...

but if i use under javascript code as extension i can't debug or see errors

```
p1 = document.getElementById('p1')

observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations){
  console.log(mutations)
});
observer.observe(p1,{
  childList :true
});
```

my goal for extension is track changes in a page an log them. 
but i can't see errors in DevTool Console for my extension.

---

EDIT:
the problem is when i load my extension, debugger in empty.(i can't see my js files)

why?

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix the JavaScript as the first step.

1- declare variables with var, let, const (also better to close code with ; you can read some "JavaScript Best Practices" by searching Google)

```
const p1 = document.getElementById('p1');
```

2- ++ is for numbers while the content of p1 is text l.e. '1'

3- You have to reassign the value back to the element

here is an example:

```
  function add(){
    const p1 = document.getElementById('p1');
    p1.textContent = parseInt(p1.textContent) +1;
  }
```

Which debugger are you using?

Did you go to `about:debugging` -> `This Nightly` -> your extension -> `inspect`?

Comment: tanks for advice. I'm new to JavaScript... however problem is I can't see my js file in Firefox DevTool

Comment: I asked explicitly ask my question in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57540629/my-extension-is-working-but-in-debugger-i-cant-see-any-thing)

Comment: yes, i exactly doing that, but in debugging tab i see "this page has no sources"

Comment: @kankan256 without seeing the actual code.. it is difficult to see.

Comment: i can't be seen  but it runs