# my extension is working but in debugger i can't see any thing

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I create an extension for firefox. Create that's manifest.json file and set that to work on "://.google.com/*". in js file of extension I wrote console.log('hello'). When I open google.com, the extension is working, but I can't see my js files in debugging section, or if I set a var in my js file, I can't access that via console.

I tried a new version of firefox(70.0a1 (2019-08-17) (64-bit)). That says if you click on inspect button, you can debug your extension. However, I can't see my files. I tried the beta version of firefox. That says you can use debug button to debug your extension, but I have the same problem.

my code in js file is

```
console.log('hello');
```

the problem is I can't see any files of my extension in devtool. (can't access variables in console, or see my js file in debugging panel.) however, the extension is working.

Answer (score 0):

Which debugger are you using?

Did you go to `about:debugging` -> `This Nightly` -> your extension -> `inspect`?